# Understanding async using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have a UI where I need animations to run smoothly. Every so often, I need to do a semi-large data calculation that makes the animation skip until it is this calculation is completed.

I am trying to get around this by making the data calculation **async** with `setTimeout`. Something like `setTimeout(calcData(), 0);`

The whole code is something like this (simplified):

```
while (animating) {
    performAnimation();
    if (needCalc) {
       setTimeout(calcData(), 0);
    }
}
```

But I still get a skip in the animation. It runs smoothly when I do not need to do any data calculations. How can I do this effectively? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little rusty in JavaScript, but I feel like there is not enough information

Comment: OK. I guess I just need to know if this is the right way to go about it or not. I'm sure this is not a unique problem, having to do large calculations while maintaining a smooth animation/UI.

Comment: Ah, then I think it is just your English. Could you please clarify on skip? I feel really dumb right now, but I'm just not getting it

Comment: I have a smooth animation that works until I need to call calcData(), it stops animating then and then restarts when calcData completes.

Comment: What is the animation? Can you use an animated gif?

Comment: JS is single threaded*: so while you evaluate something - everything else in browser freezes.

Comment: You can try putting intensive calculation in `HTML5 worker` which provides mutil-threading capacity for JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the skip because only one javascript thread is run at once. When something is done asynchronously the javascript engine puts it a queue to be ran later, then finds something else to execute. When something in the queue needs to be done the engine will pull it out and execute it, blocking all other operations until it completes.The engine then pulls something else out of its queue to execute.

So if you want to allow your render to run smoothly you must break up your calculation into multiple async calls, allowing the engine to schedule the render operation in between calculations. This is easy to accomplish if you are just iterating over a array, so you can do something like:

```
var now=Date.now;
if(window.performance&&performance.now){//use performace.now if we can
    now=performance.now;
}

function calculate(){
    var batchSize=10;//If you have a exceptionally long operation you may want to make this lower.
    var i=0;
    var next=function(){
        var start=now();
        while(now()-start<14){//14ms / frame
            var end=Math.min(i+batchSize,data.length);
            for(;i<end;i++){//do batches to reduce time overhead
                do_calc(data[i]);
            }
        }
        if(i<data.length) setTimeout(next,1)//defer to next tick
    };
    next();
}
calculate();


function render(){
    do_render_stuff();
    if(animating) {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);//use requestAnimationFrame rather then setTimeout for rendering
    }
}
render();
```

Better yet, if you can, you should use WebWorkers which work in a different thread, completely separate from the main js engine. However you are stuck with this if you need to do something you cant do in a WebWorker, such as manipulating the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, let's talk what's going on in your code:

```
while (animating) {
    performAnimation();
    if (needCalc) {
       // it should be setTimeout(calcData, 0);
       setTimeout(calcData(), 0);
    }
}
```

In line `setTimeout(calcData(), 0);` really you don't defer calling of `calcData` function, you call it, because you use `()` operator after function name.

**Secondly**, lets think, what's going on when you really make defer calling for `calcData` in the code above: commonly JavaScript is running in one thread, so, if you have code like this:

```
setTimeout(doSomething, 0);
while (true) {};
```

`doSomething` will never be called, because interpreter of javascript executes `while` loop forever and it hasn't "free time" to execute other things (even UI) . `setTimeout` - just say to schedule execution of `doSomething` when interpreter will be free and it's time to execute this function.

So, when browser executes javascript function, all other stuff become freezing.

**Solution**:

1. If you have big data that you need to process, maybe it would be better to make calculations on backend and after send results to frontend.
2. Usually when you need to make some calculation and render results it's better to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) than `while` loop. Browser will execute function passed in `requestAnimationFrame` as soon as possible, but also you give browser a time to handle other events. You can see smooth redrawing using `requestAnimationFrame` for [game](https://jsfiddle.net/end3r/9temh0ta/) (step-by-step tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Workflows/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript)).
3. If you really want to process huge amount of data at frontend part and you want to make ui works smooth, you can try to use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). WebWorkers look like threads in JavaScript, you need to communicate between main UI "thread" and WebWorker by passing messages from one to another and back and calculations on WebWorker don't affect UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, your problem boils down to your incorrect usage of setTimeout()

```
 setTimeout(calcData(), 0);
```

The first argument to setTimeout is a REFERENCE to the function that you wish to call. In your code, you are not referencing the calcData function, you are invoking it because you've included () after the function name.

Second, the fact that you've put 0 for the delay does not mean you will have a 0 second delay before the function runs. JavaScript runs in a single threaded context. The setTimeout function is placed in a queue and executed when the JavaScript engine is available, but no sooner than a minimum of 10ms or the amount you specify (whichever is less).

Realistically, your line should be:

```
   setTimeout(calcData(),10);
```